# Comparing an int and Integer

Tags: java, boxing, unboxing

In the case of below code, does the int gets boxed to an Integer or the Integer gets unboxed to an int?

```
if (mAccount.getValue() != value) { // value is Integer object
   // do something                  // mAccount.getValue() returns int
}
```

Comment: regular int comparison is done.

Comment: In this case, since `getValue()` of `Integer` gives back an `int`, a regular `int` comparison is done. However if you would have used `mAccount != value` you would compare an object reference with an `int`. (which would be a bug)